# How to initialize Array of Structure and Access each element with Pointer in C++

Tags: c++

In the following program I am having problems with structure initialization. After initialization I need to cout each strcture element using Pointer.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct student{
int rollno;
float marks;
char name[45];
}*ptr;

int main(){

    //Getting initialization error
student s1[2]={1,50.23,"abc",2,65.54,"def"};

    for(int i=0;i<2;i++){

            //Need to cout using pointers
    cout<<s1[i].rollno<<s1[i].marks<<s1[i].name;
}
return 0;
}
```

Comment: And the question is... ?

Comment: @EdS. Question is regarding how to Initialize Array of Structure and Accessing each structure element via Pointer.

Comment: Works here: http://ideone.com/1ZFgh

Comment: BTW deleted the C tag, because C is quite different in handling this code, particularly, you'd need `struct student` instead of student, etc.

Comment: @jpalecek Good to know that it works but why it isn't it working in eclipse IDE?

Comment: How doesn't it work in eclipse? Do you have error messages?

Comment: @jpalecek It works now after fixing Braces, Now how to cout struct elemnsts using pointer *ptr...?

Comment: `for( ptr=s1; ptr < s1+2; ++ptr) ...`?

Comment: @jpalecek Ok whats further in cout<<...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should wrap every member of the array in `{}`:

```
student s1[2]={{1,50.23,"abc"},{2,65.54,"def"}};
```

Comment: This is unneeded, much more a style issue.

Comment: weird. It's work fine for me. (In fact, your original code is work too, but the compiler prints warning for the missing `{}`)